# How to get user-given username and password in Spring Security SecurityConfig?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-rest

For some requirements, I need the user-given username and password from the login page. (typed by the user)

However, I could not manage to get in the following SecurityConfig's configure method.

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    **// Wants to get user-given username and password**


         auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
         .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
         .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, true from user where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, r.rolename from user u, role r where u.roleId = r.id and u.username=?");


     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well It shouldn't be done here. If you want to get user credentials you should implement it in one of your filters. For example you can define a new one.

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        if (request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().contains("application/json") && Objects.equals(((RequestFacade) request).getServletPath(), "/oauth/token")) {
            InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];

            while ((nRead = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            buffer.flush();
            byte[] json = buffer.toByteArray();

            HashMap<String, String> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
            HashMap<String, String[]> r = new HashMap<>();
            for (String key : result.keySet()) {
                String[] val = new String[1];
                val[0] = result.get(key);
                r.put(key, val);
            }

            String[] val = new String[1];
            val[0] = ((RequestFacade) request).getMethod();
            r.put("_method", val);

            HttpServletRequest s = new MyServletRequestWrapper(((HttpServletRequest) request), r);
            chain.doFilter(s, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

For example this piece of code is taking query params and putting them into request body.